# How can I revive my cat palm (chamadorea cataractarum)?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, palm

Any advice would be appreciated. Should I relocate it somewhere that receives more light? [image]

Comment: Please provode the details..how much light water etc it gets and in which part of the world you live.